# How the Linux kernel handles the memory mapping if the physical memory of say only 512 MB is installed on my system

Tags: linux-kernel

How the Linux kernel handles the memory mapping if the physical memory of say only 512 MB is installed on my system.

Kernel maps 0(or 16) MB-896MB physical RAM into 0xC0000000 linear address and can directly address it. So, what happens when I only have 512 MB of RAM?

How can the kernel map 896 MB from only 512 MB ?, the kernel set things up so that every process's page tables mapped virtual addresses from 0xC0000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF (1GB) directly to physical addresses from 0x00000000 to 0x3FFFFFFF (1GB). But when I have only 512 MB physical RAM, how can I map, virtual addresses from 0xC0000000-0xFFFFFFFF to physical 0x00000000-0x3FFFFFFF ? Point is I have a physical range of only 0x00000000-0x20000000. As kernel pages cannot be swapped out, how user processes are getting chance to use the physical memory?

Comment: Assuming a 32-bit kernel with a 3G/1G user/kernel split for process virtual memory, the process cannot map anything to the upper 1G of address space because it belongs to the kernel. That leaves 3G that the process could access, even though there is only 512M of physical memory. Most of the process page table entries will initially point to shared, read-only pages, and those pointing to uninitialized memory will point to a shared, read-only "zero page". When a shared page is written to, the kernel makes a copy and updates the page table entry. This is called "copy-on-write".

Comment: @Ian Abbot, First of all thanks for your reply. I understand the COW(copy-on-write) mechanism. My doubt is, 1. how can the kernel have linear mapping of 896 MB(kernel VAS) from only 512 MB ?. 2. (if all the 512 MB of RAM will be mapped linearly to 512MB of kernel virtual address space(0xC0000000 - 0x40000000)) then how a user process get chance to use RAM? should kernel pages be swapped out when a process tries to use RAM?

Comment: 1.The linear mapping in the kernel is mainly for the convenience of the kernel. I can't remember if the mapping includes non-present physical memory, but I'll take your word for it. 2. Even though the memory is linearly mapped into the kernel address space, the kernel can still map the physical memory pages into process address space at the same time. Memory that the kernel has allocated for its own use (not belonging to a process) never gets swapped out.

Comment: @IanAbbott, Thanks for the clarification. I just need a bit more clarity on the statement "**Memory that the kernel has allocated for its own use**" you mentioned. Are you meaning only physical memory(pages) allocated by the kernel for storing/managing data structures of the system will never be swapped out?. I think I am missing something here. could you please help me out by clarifying it?

Comment: Yes, memory allocated by `kmalloc`, `vmalloc`, `__get_free_pages`, etc. will not be swapped out.

Comment: @IanAbbott, Thanks a lot for your reply.